# Relation between supremum of quadratic variation expectation with expectation of supremum of martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

Let $X$ be a local martingale. Then the quadratic variation $[X]$ is such that $X^2-[X]$ is a local martingale.

I am tasked with showing that $$\sup_{t\geq0}\mathbb{E}([X]_t)<\infty\iff\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{t\geq0}X_t^2\right)<\infty$$ and I'm not sure how to do this using the properties of local martingales. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are allowed to use Burkholder-Davis-Gundy or BDG inequalities for $p=2$, then the result follows directly unless mistaken : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/06/the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality/